# Update image in laravel controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, post, internal-server-error

i need to use javascript to update a image file from form in controller. The server response:(Internal Server Error)
For more clarify i post my code:
the view blade..php è:

```
<div class="col">
<form action="{{ route('upload.uploadImage') }}" id="imageForm" >
 @csrf
<input type="file"   onchange="loadFile(event)"> <br>        
      <img  id="output" />

</form></div>
```

The javascript code on view:

```
var loadFile = function(event) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = reader.result;
  var file = event.target.files[0]; 

    $.ajax({
      url: $('#imageForm').attr('action'),
      method: "POST",   
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}', 
      },
      data:new FormData($('#imageForm')[0]),
      dataType:'JSON',
      contentType: false,
      cache:false,
      processData: false,
    success: (data)=> {
      console.log("Value added " + output.src);
    },
    error: function(data){
           console.log(data);}
           });

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
```

the route:

```
Route::post('/upload', [ImageController::class,'uploadImage'])->name('upload.uploadImage');
```

the ImageController:

```
 public function uploadImage(Request $request): JsonResponse
{

    dd('Controller method called');
    $image= new Image;
    $image->name=$request->input('name');
    
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file=$request->file('image');
        $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename=time().'.'.$extension;
        $file->move('public/images/',$filename);
        $image->image=$filename;
       session()->put('filename', $filename);

       $image->save();
       return response()->json(['success' => 'Post created successfully.']);
    }
}
```

Of course, head of view has the following code:

```
<head>
```

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Comment: what is the server error ?

Comment: The server response: 500 (Internal Server Error). Thank you for your support.

Comment: check Laravel error log. then you should see the actual error. it will help you to rectify the issue

Comment: In the storage/logs/laravel.log i didn't receive any message. Is there another folder when i can see? I read the message 500 in the console.

Comment: use try catch .

Comment: I solved it. the problem was that I had to defined a name for image as asked in ImageController.
Now, I need to record the imagename and recall it from user when necessary.
Thanks for your help.